# I grep parts of a JSON but when I use an input file for the strings it does not work

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I use grep on Ubuntu to copy small parts out of a large nested json file. It all works fine for individual strings, but when I try to grep multiple strings from a file with -f, the output is empty.

I have a file called names.txt. It is a long list of names with a line break for each. It looks like this:

```
Pete Smith
Bill Mayer
Sam West
Carl Bond
And so on
```

I also have a large json called data.json that I want to take parts from. Each row looks like this (`Sam West` might show up again somewhere else, possibly in a different key):

```
{
  "cities": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ],
  "licence": "asdf",
  "reg_number": 123,
  "VIPs": {
    "first": "Sam West",
    "second": "Other Name",
    "third": "Another Name"
  },
  "name": "company name"
}
```

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.

This produces an output file with the expected json in it:

`grep -i 'Sam West' data.json >> output.json`

This produces an empty output file:

`grep -if names.txt data.json >> output.json`

I expected grep to take each of the names from names.txt, search for them and return an output file with all the results. It does, however, return an empty file. Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Edit input and output **into** your question, not comments. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Don't use `grep` to query a JSON file. Use `jq` instead.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. I need the output to be smaller json files though. I was not able to achieve that with `jq` but I am happy to learn what I did wrong.

Comment: What you've done should work.  Perhaps names.txt has tabs or dos line endings.